# What's the meaning of `State` and `PfxRcd`?

Tags: cisco, router, bgp

When I execute the `show ip bgp summary`, I get the bellow data:

```
Neighbor        V    AS MsgRcvd MsgSent   TblVer  InQ OutQ Up/Down  State/PfxRcd
12.0.0.2        4   200     199     190        12    0    0 00:17:27        4
2.2.2.2         4   200       0       0        12    0    0 03:06:27        4
```

you see the State there is nothing shows. and the PfxRcd is `4`.

what's the meaning of `State` and `PfxRcd`?

and in the Router the `12.0.0.2` is accessible, and `2.2.2.2` is inaccessible（I mean can not ping）, why the neighbor `2.2.2.2` also get `4` prefix routes.

---

**edit-01**

when I show bgp neighbors:

```
BGP neighbor is 2.2.2.2,  remote AS 200, external link
  BGP version 4, remote router ID 0.0.0.0
  BGP state = Active, up for 08:33:23
  Last read 08:33:23, last write 08:33:23, hold time is 180, keepalive interval is 60 seconds
  Neighbor capabilities:
    Route refresh: advertised and received(new)
    Address family IPv4 Unicast: advertised and received
  Message statistics:
    InQ depth is 0
    OutQ depth is 0

                         Sent       Rcvd
    Opens:                  0          0
    Notifications:          0          0
    Updates:                0          0
    Keepalives:             0          0
    Route Refresh:          0          0
    Total:                  0          0
  Default minimum time between advertisements runs is 30 seconds

 For address family: IPv4 Unicast
  BGP table version 12, neighbor version 6/0
  Output queue size : 0
  Index 1, Offset 0, Mask 0x2
  1 update-group member
                                 Sent       Rcvd
  Prefix activity:               ----       ----
    Prefixes Current:               0          0 (Consumes 0 bytes)
    Prefixes total:                 0          0
    Implicit Withdraw:              0          0
    Explicit Withdraw:              0          0
    Used as bestpath:             n/a          1
    Used as multipath:            n/a          0

                                       Outbound    Inbound
      Local Policy Denied Prefixes:    --------    -------
        Total:                                0          0
      Number of NLRIs in the update sent: max 3, min 1

  Connections established 0; dropped 0
  Last reset never
  Transport(tcp) path-mtu-discovery is enabled
Connection state is ESTAB, I/O status: 1, unread input bytes: 0 
Connection is ECN Disabled, Minimum incoming TTL 0, Outgoing TTL 1
Connection tableid (VRF): 0

Enqueued packets for retransmit: 0, input: 0  mis-ordered: 0 (0 bytes)

Event Timers (current time is 0xC69F4):
Timer          Starts    Wakeups            Next
Retrans             0          0             0x0
TimeWait            0          0             0x0
AckHold             0          0             0x0
SendWnd             0          0             0x0
KeepAlive           0          0             0x0
GiveUp              0          0             0x0
PmtuAger            0          0             0x0
DeadWait            0          0             0x0
Linger              0          0             0x0
ProcessQ            0          0             0x0

iss: 2057115318  snduna: 2057115748  sndnxt: 2057115748     sndwnd:  15955
irs: 3480424370  rcvnxt: 3480424751  rcvwnd:      16004  delrcvwnd:    380

SRTT: 259 ms, RTTO: 579 ms, RTV: 320 ms, KRTT: 0 ms
minRTT: 16 ms, maxRTT: 300 ms, ACK hold: 200 ms
Status Flags: passive open, gen tcbs
Option Flags: nagle, path mtu capable
IP Precedence value : 6

Datagrams (max data segment is 1460 bytes):
Rcvd: 0 (out of order: 0), with data: 0, total data bytes: 0
Sent: 0 (retransmit: 0, fastretransmit: 0, partialack: 0, Second Congestion: 0), with data: 0, total data bytes: 0
 Packets received in fast path: 0, fast processed: 0, slow path: 0
 fast lock acquisition failures: 0, slow path: 0
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means how many prefixes have been received from the neighbor, 4 means just that it has gotten 4 prefixes from 12.0.0.2 and 4 prefixes from 2.2.2.2.

If you do show ip bgp neighbor 12.0.0.2 received-routes you can see which prefixes did you actually get from that neighbor.

Regarding 2.2.2.2, is there an arp entry for it if you do show arp?

Comment: hi, brother, the `2.2.2.2` is not access from my Router, so why there have the prefixes?

Comment: It would be possible for there to be an established connection without ping, therefore I was interested if there is an arp entry for 2.2.2.2. But you could also check what the output of 'show ip bgp neighbor 2.2.2.2' is.